# Cognos Report Studio: CASE and IF Statements

Tags: cognos, cognos-8

I'm very new in using Cognos report studio and trying to filter some of the values and replace them into others.

I currently have values that are coming out as blanks and want to replace them as string "Property Claims"

what i'm trying to use in my main query is

CASE WHEN [Portfolio] is null
then 'Property Claims'
ELSE [Portfolio]

which is giving me an error. Also have a different filter i want to put in to replace windscreen flags to a string value rather than a number. For example if the flag is 1 i want to place it as 'Windscreen Claims'.

if [Claim Windscreen Flag] = 1
then ('Windscreen')
Else [Claim Windscreen Flag]

None of this works with the same error....can someone give me a hand?

Comment: Any luck with the suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Your first `CASE` statement is missing the `END`.  The error message should be pretty clear.  But there is a simpler way to do that:

```
coalesce([Portfolio], 'Property Claims')
```

The second problem is similar:  Your `IF...THEN...ELSE` statement is missing a bunch of parentheses.  But after correcting that you may have problems with incompatible data types.  You may need to cast the numbers to strings:

```
case
  when [Claim Windscreen Flag] = 1 then ('Windscreen')
  else cast([Claim Windscreen Flag], varchar(50))
end
```

In future, please include the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

it might be syntax

- IS NULL  (instead of = null)
- NULL is not blank.  You might also want = ' '
- case might need an else and END at the bottom
- referring to a data type as something else can cause errors.  For example a numeric like [Sales] = 'Jane Doe'

For example (assuming the result is a string and data item 2 is also a string),

```
case
when([data item 1] IS NULL)Then('X')
when([data item 1] = ' ')Then('X')
else([data item 2])
end
```

Also, if you want to show a data item as a different type, you can use CAST

Comment: Yeah, Cognos used to allow you to mix data types in a case statement, but that went away a few years ago, I think.